# Setting cache-control on files with no extension

Tags: htaccess, cache-control

We are using ExpressionEngine as a CMS. It allows you to set the "type" of the file when you create a template and when naming it, you don't have to give it an extension.

I have used this to set cache-control but it doesn't work on many of my javascript and css files because they don't have .css and .js extensions. Is there a way to make it work on type?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On 
    # Default directive
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 6 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 months"
    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 4 months"
    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 6 months"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
        application/javascript \
        application/json \
        application/rss+xml \
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
        application/x-font-ttf \
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
        application/xhtml+xml \
        application/xml \
        font/opentype \
        image/svg+xml \
        image/x-icon \
        text/css \
        text/html \
        text/javascript \
        text/plain \
        text/x-js \
        text/x-component \
        text/xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 
# configure mod_headers
# 
# URL: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html
# 
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "type" I assume you mean *mime-type*, in which case you should look at [mod_expires and the `ExpiresByType` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype) - this is undoubtedly the easiest/modern way to set the appropriate `Expires` and `Cache-Control` (`max-age` directive) HTTP response headers.

It goes something like:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
```

This is using the "alternative syntax". Ensure that the mime-types stated match the mime-types that your server is responding with. (`2692000` seconds would seem to be close to `1 month`)

However, if you *need* to modify other directives of the `Cache-Control` header then you will still need to use the `Header` directive.

> ```
> <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
> ```

Aside: the double backslash at the start of the regex is superfluous, you only need to escape the literal dot. ie. `"\.(ico|` etc.

**UPDATE:**

> I already have the ExpiresByType info set.

The `Header` directive (mod_headers) will take priority *if the corresponding `FilesMatch` container matches*. However, you say that many of these files "don't have .css and .js extensions", so it's not going to match and the `ExpiresByType` directives are going to take priority in these instances.

You do have a conflict of interests between your mod_expires and mod_headers directives. With mod_expires (`ExpiresByType`) you are trying to cache CSS and JS files for 4 and 6 months respectively, with mod_headers (`Header`) you state a cache time of 1 month for both?! So, without a file extension present, these files are going to be cached for 4 and 6 months, regardless of your `Header` directive.

Also, you should note that the `ExpiresByType` directive also sets the `Expires` HTTP response header (for old browsers). This is going to conflict with the `Cache-Control` header that you are manually setting with the `Header` directive. Although all modern browsers *should* prioritise `Cache-Control` over `Expires`.

Basically, you don't need to use `Header set Cache-Control ...` if you are using mod_expires. Or, if you do, you need to make sure they are both doing the same thing.

Comment: I already have the ExpiresByType info set. Does the Cache-Control  override that or vice-versa? I do need to set the max-age attribute.

Comment: Both the `ExpiresByType` and `Headers` directives in the (updated) code in your question set the `max-age` attribute of the `Cache-Control` header. This is a conflict. I've updated my answer.