# How do I set expired headers in .htaccess to prevent getting an F from Yslow?

Tags: wordpress, headers

I have an F on Yslow, because of expired headers.

I have tried all the solutions from similar question and only got partial success.

Here's my *.htaccess* file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
### activate mod_expires
ExpiresActive On
### Expire .gif’s 1 month from when they’re accessed (Default algorithm)
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
### Expire .jpg’s 1 month from when they’re accessed
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
### Expire .png’s 1 month from when they’re accessed
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
### Expire .js’s 7 days from when they’re accessed (Alternative algorithm)
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 7 days"
### Expire .css’s 30 days from when they’re accessed
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 days"
### Expire everything else 1 day from when it’s last modified
ExpiresDefault "modification plus 1 day"

</IfModule>    

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you add the `ExpiresByType` items?   If so you should add them outside the section labeled as handled by WordPress.   WordPress may just overwrite everything in that section.

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99039/setting-cache-control-on-files-with-no-extension

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a few issues with your current config file:

1. You are trying to use both mod_expires and mod_headers to set the same cache headers (but with different values?). mod_expires sets the `max-age` parameter of the `Cache-Control` header, as well as the older `Expires` header. This is likely to result in conflict (particularly since you are trying to set different values with each). mod_headers is likely to win. Using mod_expires is preferable. However, if you *need* to set specific `Cache-Control` headers then you will need to use mod_headers.
2. `ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 7 days"`
   Your server is unlikely responding with a `text/js` mime-type for JavaScript files. So, this probably isn't doing anything. Check what mime-type your server is sending and specify that. It's probably `application/javascript`.
3. The `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` container is *inside* the `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` container?
4. Remove the `<IfModule>` wrappers. Any errors? The `<IfModule>` wrappers are only required if your site should function correctly without these modules installed (if you are moving your site from server to server), or if certain directives from another module are dependent on a particular module being installed. If you use `<IfModule>` wrappers around everything then your system simply *fails silently* when the module is not installed, rather than alerting you to an error. So, it might simply be failing silently. An error is usually preferable!
5. As Stephen pointed out in comments, if you have all these directives within the `# BEGIN..END WordPress` comments then they are likely to be overwritten with the next WP update.